# How to extract a single word from an os.system command?

Tags: python, linux

I'm writing a python program where I do some `os.system(cmd)`.
I would need to extract one single word from the terminal output. The output contains a seire of informations. Inside this information, I only need the parameter `address`, as a simple string. How could I do?
This is an example of the ouput:

```
  --------------------------------
  General            |  dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/1
                     |       type: default
  --------------------------------
  Status             |  connected: yes
                     |  suspended: no
                     |  interface: wwp0s20f0u3i2
                     | ip timeout: 20
  --------------------------------
  Properties         |        apn: wap.tim.it
                     |    roaming: allowed
  --------------------------------
  IPv4 configuration |     method: static
                     |    address: 10.200.210.208
                     |     prefix: 27
                     |    gateway: 10.200.210.209
                     |        dns: 217.200.201.65, 217.200.201.64
                     |        mtu: 1500
  --------------------------------
  Statistics         |   duration: 1290
```

I've done:

```
  proc=subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, )
  output=proc.communicate()[0]
  print(output)
```

but obviously, it returns the entire output. Also including a `grep` inside the command, isn't a good solution. The output is bad formatted. I would need:

```
10.200.210.208
```

Comment: The title mentioning os.system implies problems you don't actually have since you're using `subprocess` instead.

Comment: Consume the entire contents of the pipe (as a string) then use a regular expression to isolate the IP address

Comment: Isn't there some basic Python command to find the IPv4 network address of a computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might regular expression for that task following way

```
import re
output = '''  --------------------------------
  General            |  dbus path: /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Bearer/1
                     |       type: default
  --------------------------------
  Status             |  connected: yes
                     |  suspended: no
                     |  interface: wwp0s20f0u3i2
                     | ip timeout: 20
  --------------------------------
  Properties         |        apn: wap.tim.it
                     |    roaming: allowed
  --------------------------------
  IPv4 configuration |     method: static
                     |    address: 10.200.210.208
                     |     prefix: 27
                     |    gateway: 10.200.210.209
                     |        dns: 217.200.201.65, 217.200.201.64
                     |        mtu: 1500
  --------------------------------
  Statistics         |   duration: 1290'''
address = re.search("address: ([0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+[.][0-9]+)",output).group(1)
print(address) # 10.200.210.208
```

Explanation: I use pattern with single capturing group, encased in `(` `)` which I then access using `.group(1)`

Disclaimer: I assume address line is always present and address is in form of 4 base-10 numbers sheared by `.` character.

Note: for brevity I set `output` to multiline string, rather than calling command.

Comment: This is well done! For style points, I would use \. instead of [.]... but it works the same either way

Comment: @Cargo23, whereas I consider `[.]` better regex style -- it works across languages with less regard to quoting context, whereas `\.` is more likely to have the backslash interpreted in an unexpected way -- sometimes needing to be doubled, etc.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That is a great point, you are a gentleman and a scholar!

Answer (score 0):

Python has elagent & simple text processing methods which can used to extract the data like so using [string.find](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rfind.html)

```
s = output
start = 'address'
end = 'prefix'
mask =  (s[s.find(start)+len(start):s.rfind(end)])
print(mask)
```

outputs #

```
: 10.200.210.208
```

Later if you want you clean output like so

```
mask = mask.replace(":",'').replace('|','')
print(mask)
```

which outputs #

```
10.200.210.208
```